# How to SET X=Y conditionally in Oracle Merge Update?

Tags: sql, oracle

In my merge statement, I want to set these two values conditionally

```
MERGE INTO 
...
...
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
NC.A=OC.Date IF NC.status='D', 
NC.B=OC.Date IF NC.status='O';
```

Can this be done within a MERGE statement? I've heard of DECODE and was wondering if perhaps that can be used. I've tried CASE and IF statements but they did not work.

Anyone have experience/ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect CASE expressions to work.  Try:

```
MERGE INTO 
...
...
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    NC.A = CASE WHEN NC.status = 'D' THEN OC.Date ELSE NC.A END,
    NC.B = CASE WHEN NC.STATUS = 'O' THEN OC.Date ELSE NC.B END;
```

Give that a shot.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks!! I don't know why mine didn't work though. I had case before NC.A. I think I might have accidentally added the semicolon in both cases, that's why I thought this wasn't allowed :/

Comment: Nvm, I'm getting a "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables" error. Don't know if it is related or not though.

Comment: Given the information presented I'm not able to judge. Does the `decode` solution from @GolezTrol's answer work any better?

Comment: From a Google search, it appears the problem is unrelated and with the ON clause returning multiple rows. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a `case` statement, as demonstrated by Bob Jarvis in his excellent answer.

You asked about `decode`. `decode` is basically a case-statement-as-a-function, so that will work as well:

```
MERGE INTO 
...
...
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    NC.A = decode(NC.status, 'D', OC.Date, NC.A),
    NC.B = decode(NC.STATUS, 'O', OC.Date, NC.B);
```

Personally I'd use `case` over `decode` almost any time, since you only save a couple of characters while `decode` is less readable (you have to count parameters to see which is which).

Whichever you choose; the trick is to set NC.A to NC.A in case the condition is *not* met. You cannot add a condition to the setting itself. You always assign a value to NC.A, so the only way to leave it unmodified is to set it to the value it already had.

Note though, that any update triggers will be fired for those rows. Oracle just sees an attempt to modify the record and will fire the trigger regardsless whether the data is the same or not.